# How to just just one packer build

Tags: packer

Sorry if this is a silly question but I am new to packer and haven't been able to find the answer.

In my root directory I have 4 files.

```
be.pkr.hcl
data.pkr.hcl
fe.pkr.hcl
variables.pkr.hcl
```

I have been running this command so far which builds both of by builds

```
packer build .
```

My question is how can I just run one of my builds? I know I can copy my variables and data into each build but is there a better way so I can include them and run this for example

```
packer build fe.pkr.hcl
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use the [only argument](https://www.packer.io/docs/commands/build#only-foo-bar-baz) to `packer build` for this. You can specify the build argument names like `-only=amazon-ebs.my_ami` if you do not rename the build in your template, or otherwise specify multiple kv pairs within the block.